# How to automatically pass on all the picture file paths to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, directory

I need to add a bunch of playing cards jpg paths into an array, so that I can assign them later as src="" of 
Alternatively add the jpg paths to an object

I'm working with javascript, I'm not too sure if it should be a syncronous or async function. 
i got this from some other stackoverflow question, but i don't understand it and it doesn't work. I don't understand the fs stuff.

```
const fs = require('fs');


fs.readdirSync("pics").forEach(file => {
  console.log(file);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

fs.readdirSync("pics") already returns an array.

Your code should be:

```
const pathArray = fs.readdirSync("pics");
```

As long as "pics" is the path of the folder you want to read from.

Comment: doesn't work, says fs is not defined. and if I do this "const fs = require('fs')" then console says require is not defined

Comment: This is a different issue. Are you running this in a browser or through node? This code block is supposed to be run through node.